# How to convert laravel mix webpack config into bun bundler

Tags: javascript, node.js, laravel-mix, bun, webpack-mix

```js
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix
  .alias({
    '@app1': './resources/app1/src',
    '@app2': './resources/app2/src',
  });

mix
  .ts('resources/app1/src/index.tsx', 'js/app1.js')
  .ts('resources/app2/src/index.tsx', 'js/app2.js')
  .react();

mix
  .sass('resources/astnext/src/styles/app1.scss', 'css/app1.css')
  .sass('resources/astnext/src/styles/app2.scss', 'css/app2.css')
  .options({
    processCssUrls: false,
    postCss: [require('tailwindcss')],
  });

if (mix.inProduction()) {
  mix
    .version()
    .sourceMaps(false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Install the most recent version of [Bun](https://bun.sh/) globally, use the following command:

```
npm install -g bun
```

Alternative installation methods can be found in the documentation. Please refer to the [documentation](https://bun.sh/docs/installation) for more details.

- Replace all instances of `npm run ...` commands in the `package.json` file with `bun ...`

I have not conducted testing; this substitution should work, as Bun serves as a wrapper.

Comment: This was the same approach that I had taken, alas I ended up unsuccessful so far.  I was able to `bun install`, but when I try to run my laravel-mix scripts via bun, it always errored out complaining that `resolve` is not a function.  I have yet to figure it out, but didn't get to spend much time on it yet.